# Наклоны объектов

Tags: java, android, математика

Не могу додуматься как реализовать функцию поворота объекта. У меня записываются первые только две точки (образующие вертикальную линию), остальные дорисовываются по ним. При повороте я буду знать всегда эти две точки, вопрос: Как мне узнать координаты двух других точек, образующих горизонтальную линию.  Буду благодарен помощи!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление**

Я хочу чтобы объект нарисованный на картинке наклонялся при онтаче на любой градус. У меня сейчас проблема в том что вертикальная линия наклоняется, а горизонтальная остается на месте, так как я не знаю как у нее изменяются координаты при повороте.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

тут два преобразования, если я правильно понял вопрос, то, навскидку, алгоритм примерно таков:

1. возьмём вертикальный отрезок за основу.

   ```
   P0 и P1 - координаты (x,y) исходного отрезка, 
   Q0 и Q1 - координаты преобразованного отрезка
   ```
2. преобразование параллельного переноса вычисляется из разности начальных и преобразованных координат какой-либо точки фигуры (возьмём для удобства точку соединения перпендикулярных отрезков на рисунке)

   ```
   T.x = Q0.x - P0.x
   T.y = Q0.y - P0.y
   ```
3. Преобразование поворота. с ним чуть сложнее. косинус и синус угла поворота можно добыть так:

   ```
   A.x = P1.x - P0.x  ; A - исходный вектор
   A.y = P1.y - P0.y  
   B.x = Q1.x - Q0.x ; B - преобразованный вектор
   B.y = Q1.y - Q0.y
   cosF = (A.x * B.x + A.y * B.y) / (sqrt(A.x^2 + A.y^2) * sqrt(B.x^2 + B.y^2))
   sinF = sqrt(1 - cosA^2);
   ```
4. далее применяем ко всем остальным точкам преобразования поворота и затем переноса

   ```
   S - исходная точка
   D - преобразованная точка
   D.x = T.x + S.x * cosF - S.y * sinF
   D.y = T.y + S.x * sinF + S.y * cosF
   ```

Comment: sinF = sqrt(1 - cosA^2) ? Тут cosF^2?